# Need live cd or usb of original 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, usb, touchpad

I need a copy of original desktop Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit live CD (or live USB). Not the alternative copy.

Can I buy one or can someone give me step by step directions to make one. I have issues with an hp touchpad. I want to try the tpdebrick-v004 solution.

I have Windows 7. If someone has a link that I can download- great. I see that 12.1 has been useful for some people to use the tpdebrick-v004 method. If someone has a better way to do it please let me know. It started out as a what the heck maybe I can fix it, to a mission with many hours wasted.

Help please. :)

Answer (score 1):

This link is a list of Old Ubuntu releases:

[Old Ubuntu Releases](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/)

Answer (score 1):

You can download the iso here http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ (the second link). 
In win7 in order to burn the iso file:

- Insert a recordable CD, DVD, or Blu‑ray Disc into your disc burner.
- Open Computer by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, and then clicking Computer.
- In Windows Explorer, find the disc image file, and then double-click it.
- If you have more than one disc burner, from the Disc burner list in Windows Disc Image Burner, click the burner that you want to use.
- (Optional) If you want to verify that the disc image was burned correctly to the disc, select the Verify disc after burning check box.
- If the integrity of disc image file is critical (for example, the disc image file contains a firmware update), you should select this check box.
- Click Burn to burn the disc.

Source: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/burn-a-cd-or-dvd-from-an-iso-file

I don't use windows at home and have no cd burner at work.